# Can't get Curl output into JSON

Tags: php, json, curl

Time for a second set of eyes.  I've been looping on this for awhile. The url http://freegeoip.net/json/ appears to return JSON.  I can't seem to decode or parse it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code follows:

```
    <?php

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Debug options
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     error_reporting(E_ALL);
     error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
     ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    function get_ip_address()
    {
        foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true) {
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip) {
            if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) !== false) {
                return $ip;
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }

    $myIP = get_ip_address();

    $url = "http://freegeoip.net/json/" . $myIP;
    $cURL = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json'
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($cURL);
    $myArray = json_decode($result);

    curl_close($cURL);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Debug  
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     echo $myArray->region_code . "<br />";
     echo $myArray->region_name . "<br />";
     echo $myArray->city . "<br />";
     echo $myArray->zip_code . "<br />";
     echo $myArray->time_zone . "<br />";
     echo $myArray->latitude . "<br />";
     echo $myArray->longitude . "<br />";
     echo $myArray->metro_code . "<br />";
```

Comment: Are you sure your curl is working? Have you tried to just dump the $result out to see what it contains? Might be that its empty, which would shift your search for a solution to one way or the other.

Comment: _"I can't seem to decode or parse it."_ You're going to need to be a little less vague. What error(s) are you seeing? What output are you expecting? What output are you getting?

Comment: I copy pasted your entire code to a test script on my server, and it works as expected. Debug lines output, and I get results about my IP.

Comment: I'm at least looking for it to return a country of United States.  It seem to be getting "non Object"for the $myArray calls in the last lines.

Comment: This suggests your `json_decode()` is failing, which suggests your `$result` doesn't contain JSON. `var_dump()` it to check.

Comment: I worked yesterday!  Now it's not returning an object.  Randall, thanks for trying.

Comment: try `json_decode($result,false);` to see if it will force it into an object , it's supposed to return an object, but it might be a setting

Comment: Hmm. How many times did your server hit their server with this? It could be something as simple as they are now blacklisting your server IP: "_You're allowed up to 15,000 queries per hour by default. Once this limit is reached, all of your requests will result in HTTP 403, forbidden, until your quota is cleared._"

Comment: var_dump($result); Yields: string(5577) "
Please enable cookies.
One more step
Please complete the security check to access freegeoip.net
Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?

Comment: The $result,false made no changes.   To my knowledge,I have gone there no more than a 100 times in the last couple of days.

Comment: Randall, how can I check on my quota? It makes sense, especially if the code worked for you.

Comment: It actually sounds from the dump you showed... that they are blocking an automated script (aka bot) by wanting verification first. You may have to get yourself whitelisted with them (look to their homepage for contact info), OR host your own node to work with it locally. Either case, they are clearly doing a blocker on you for whatever reasons they have :(

Comment: I found that if I remove $myIP it returns a generic set of values from out east in the correct form.  However using my phone (Not on WIFI) it blocks it.

Comment: I got my IPs crossed. It's not blocking the $myIP, but it appears to be blocking the IP of the origin of the CURL request.   I think you nailed it Randall.

Answer (score -1):

Edit : Removed answer.

I put the code into my server and it works perfectly fine for me.

Maybe curl is disabled on his server?

Comment: You do realize that having that or not makes zero difference on the execution of a php script, right? http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php